# Tomcat JDBCRealm redirection after successful login complication

Tags: tomcat, nginx, jdbcrealm

I have a java web application which is being served by apache tomcat on port 8080. We have instructed nginx to serve the application based on following configuration:

```
location ~ ^/conference/(.*)$ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1;
}
```

As you can see there should be a 'conference' keyword present in URL of all requests destined for this application.

We have made use of JDBCRealm for authentication purposes. So lets say I have entered 'http://example.com/conference/conferencearchive' in the address bar. After entering a valid username and matching password in the login form, I would expect to be redirected to the page I asked for but instead I'll get a redirection to 'http://example.com/conferencearchive/'.

What happens to the 'conference' part of the url?

Answer (score 0):

See the parentheses in the location match ^/conference/(.*)$

The $1 in the proxypass directive is only supplying the part of the url in the parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But this not a defect. Our application is in ROOT directory of tomcat webapps so when nginx receives such a request, it correctly removes the 'conference' part of the url and proxies the remaining part to tomcat. The problem is that when we get redirected from JDBCRealm there is no 'conference' in the URL so nginx can not match it with our directive.

Comment: Oh right. In that case I'd add a ServletFilter where you detect login (check lack of principal before doFilter and has a principal afterwards. Then send a redirect to the home page.